# How can I rename image file based on colors in the image?

Tags: command-line, convert, image-processing, batch-rename

For example:

If I have a 2x2-pixel image.

In the image:

- 3 pixels are red.
- 1 pixel is green.
- 0 pixels are blue.

I want to rename the image to `3_1_0`.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any app that can do this. But a developer sight is, writing an application to do some mathematics calculations and fetch the RGB numbers, then rename file via bash commands.

Comment: What do you currently use to determine the number of pixels for each color?

Comment: In other words: How do you define “red”, “green” and “blue”?

Answer (score 2):

To get the amount of pixels for red would be:

```
convert image -fill black +opaque "rgb(255,0,0)" -fill white -opaque "rgb(255,0,0)" -format "%[fx:w*h*mean]" info:
```

- 0,255,0 for green and 0,0,255 for blue
- But 255,1,0 is basically also a red.

The remainder of this would be to create a python/bash script to loop over your images, loop over the convert for your colors and maybe shades and then copy or rename the file.